# magento 1 : how to send automatic reminder for incomplete orders in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I need to get a list of customers that did not pay yet every 2 days in my mail or anything to keep track on them.

How can I create a notification for orders that are not completed in system?

Comment: i am using this extension for it https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html. but it is not working

Comment: means are you teling you want to send email for customers who `add products to cart and didt purchase` ?

Comment: yes. you are getting my point. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of free extensions are available [here1](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html) & [here2](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-carts-notifications-1.html)

Also make sure you are sending mails through `mail server` & **cron jobs** are working fine....

```
class Web4pro_Abandonedcart_Block_Email_Order_Items extends Mage_Sales_Block_Items_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('web4pro_abandonedcart/email_order_items.phtml');
    }

    public function getTax($_item)
    {
        if (Mage::helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax()){
            $subtotal = Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax') . ' : ' .Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total_incl_tax']);
        } elseif(Mage::helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) {
            $subtotal = Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax') . ' : ' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total']) . '<br>'. Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax') . ' : ' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total_incl_tax']);
        } else {
            $subtotal = Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax') . ' : ' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total']);
        }
        return $subtotal;
    }

    public function getImage($_item)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($_item->getProductId());
        if($product->getImage()=="no_selection"&&$product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
            $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
            $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
            foreach ($simple_collection as $simple_product) {
                if ($simple_product->getImage() != "no_selection") {
                    $imageUrl = $simple_product->getThumbnailUrl();
                }
            }
        } else {
            $imageUrl = $product->getThumbnailUrl();
        }
        return $imageUrl;
    }

}
```

Note : its better to try extensions in demo sites and than try in live site.....

Comment: i tried with both extension both are working in admin successfully. but not sending mail.

Comment: i can not understand how to set cron job or check mail server can you suggest me please.

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari wait until one hour and make sure you configured extensions properly in backend, after 1 hour it will send email.....

Comment: last one week i am doing it. but i did not get mail i have checked with it please tell me how to set cron job or mail server

Comment: if any emails are sending in site means than mail server is installed in server, if you are using `smtp extension` to send e mails means than these extensions will not work, also intall this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html to check `cron jobs` working or not..... @ErSarveshVTiwari

Comment: contact us mail, order mail is sending from my site. i am checking it on local server.

Comment: if those emails are sending means and if you didt installed any smtp extension means `mail server is installed`, now you need to check `cron jobs` @ErSarveshVTiwari